# Update the column I searched for

Tags: cassandra

is there any possibility to update a column-value in cassandra that I searched for (is part of my primary key)?

I have a (huge) list of items with a field calld "LastUpdateDateTime" and from time to time I search for columns that haven't updated for a while.

So, the reason i searched for this columns is cause I want to update them and after I update them I want to set the timestamp to the current date.

How to do this with cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't update primary key column, It will insert another record.**

That's how cassandra work.

May be you will have to use spark-cassandra connector OR Delete the records with old values and insert new values.

**Note:** Deleting and inserting is not recommended if you have many records as it will create corresponding number of tombstones

Comment: Hmm okay, what about a secondary index ?